# ¿Cómo llenar una columna en google sheet automáticamente con apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un documento en google sheets el cual tengo que hacer que se llene una columna en especifico cada que un usuario ingresa al un link.

```js
function datos(){
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID);
    const registro = sheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    const fila = registro.getRange() + 1;
    registro.getRange(fila, 17).setValue("mensaje");
}
```

| A | B | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dato | Dato |  |
| Mas datos | Mas Datos |  |
|  |  | Mensaje |
|  |  | Mensaje |

En lugar de que el mensaje que se escriba en la posición `C1` se escribe hasta abajo de toda la tabla.
Me pudieran ayudar a saber cómo puedo hacer que se imprima desde `C1` hasta la ultima celda de la tabla.

La tabla de arriba solo es un ejemplo en mi documento, mi tabla tiene 22 columnas, exactamente quiero que la columna dónde se escriba el mensaje sea desde `Q3` hasta donde termine la tabla.

Estuve checando consultando en paguinas que habalan a cerca de google apps script y google sheet y encontre este codigo:

```js
   function registrarAsistencia(correo, id, nombre) {
  // Debes cambiar este identificador por el de tu documento de hoja de cálculo
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GprWyWzgjf9IFtKPryxlMXn0XfOieEhK3P3Sgto");
  const asistencia = sheet.getSheetByName("Asistencia");
  const lastRow = asistencia.getLastRow() + 1;
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(correo);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue(id);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 3).setValue(nombre);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(new Date());
}
```

En mi documento tengo n número de filas, por lo cual no sé cómo hacer para que se recorra la columna y si una celda está en blanco la escriba el mensaje en esa posición en lugar de que lo escriba hasta abajo de toda la tabla.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. El código en la pregunta tiene un error que impediría que escriba datos . ¿Lo has pasado correctamente? Por otro lado, no queda clara la relevancia de la mención de la web app. Elimina la información innecesaria, corrige el código y agrega una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos de búsqueda en este sitio como se sugiere en [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está escribiendo hasta abajo debido a que la fila en la cual escribir se está determinando por medio de `Sheet.getLastRow()` el cual devuelve la última fila con datos de la hoja. Para escribir en la posición C1, deberías pasar 1 como número de fila. Cabe mencionar siempre que sea posible debe buscarse usar el menor número de llamadas a servicios de Apps Script porque son muy lentos.

Cambia

```
  const lastRow = asistencia.getLastRow() + 1;
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(correo);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue(id);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 3).setValue(nombre);
  asistencia.getRange(lastRow, 4).setValue(new Date());
```

por

```
const row = 1; // número de la fila en la que quieres escribir los datos
asistencia.getRange(row,1,1,4).setValues([[correo,id,nombre,new Date()]])
```

Para escribir en la primera celda vacía, deberás leer la columna y luego iterar hasta encontrar la primera celda vacía, por ejemplo

```
const values = asistencia.getRange('C:C').getValues(); // Leer todos los valores de la columna C
let index = 0; // Los índices de los Arrays en JavaScript empiezan en 0
while(values[index][0] !== ''){
  index++;
}
const row = index + 1; // Los números de fila en la hoja de cálculo empiezan en 1
```

Nota: Este código asume que siembre habrá al menos una celda vacía. Quizás debes de tomar medidas para manejar el caso de que no haya celdas vacías.

Comment: Hice los cambios que me comentaste gracias. Cuando le doy deploy me aparece un error de que la propiedad '0' no se puede leer (de la condición while(values[index][0]!= '').

Comment: Es muy probable que values no tenga una celda vacía (véase la nota al final de la respuesta). Si requires mayor orientción, agrega una nueva pregunta incluyendo un [mcve] (además del código incluye datos fuente de ejemplo así como del resultado esperado)